# How to serve HTTP content from a port in Java

Tags: java, network-programming, port, activemq-classic

When I run ActiveMQ by executing the batch file in its bin/ directory, I am able to go to its admin/management console by opening a web browser and going to `http://localhost:8161/admin/`.

This has me curious.

This is my local sandbox and I do not have any web server (`httpd` or otherweise) installed. So how is it that ActiveMQ is able to "register" a port on my machine, and listen to it exclusively?

If I try to go to `http://localhost:8162/admin/` (notice the different port #), I get an *unable to connect* error.

Somewhere, somehow, AMQ is saying "map this URI (`localhost:8161`) to some root directory on this machine". As a programmer, I'm interested in how something like this works.

Comment: How do you think `httpd` does it, and why wouldn't ActiveMQ be able to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read up on sockets: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).  All a web server is, is a socket listener that handles the HTTP protocol.  HTTP protocol is [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

Web servers often handle a lot of other things, but that is the basics.  If you want a small program that also runs a web server I suggest not re-inventing the wheel.  Try incorporating [jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) into your server.

Comment: I was planning on setting up a GlassFish server. Could I just configure GF to listen on a certain port for me, then (somehow) map HTTP requests on that port to my servlets?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with glassfish configuration, here is what I could find with a google though: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2427/ghmos.html#gkrgo

Comment: Thank you DMoses for taking the time to explain what is going on under the hood, and for finding that reference for me!

Answer (score 3):

A Java process is able to use any port (>= 1024 on linux) as a web server or for any other purpose.  You don't need a separate web server to do this

Comment: Java is perfectly capable of using ports < 1024, as is any other process. It's a question of OS permissions, not the type of process.

Comment: You just have be running as root. ;)

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ starts an embedded [Jetty server](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), which listens for HTTP connections on that port. You don't need any other server running. It's all done from Java. If you dig down deep enough, you'll find some variety of [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) at the bottom of it all. You can learn all about sockets and listening on ports in the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).

Comment: Thanks Ryan - can you please read my comment to DMoses' reponse? Same question for you: could I just set a GlassFish server to do this for me?

Comment: @Adam: It's not very clear what you're looking for. I think what you're asking for is exactly what servlet containers are built to do. In that case, any of [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), Glassfish (actually [Grizzly](http://java.net/projects/grizzly-servlet-container)), [Winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/), or any of a multitude of commercial products will work virtually identically--bind to a port, receive HTTP requests, and let you create responses using a [servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html).

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest level, ActiveMQ is creating a ServerSocket instance within itself and listening for connections using this server socket.  A socket is always bound to a port.

Answer (score 0):

One: this port is greater than (or equal to) 1024, so it means a "non root" user can listen on it.

Second: you can bind to ports from dedicated addresses only. This means ActiveMQ may have only opened that port on 127.0.0.1 (localhost). Try and see if you can open that URL from your external interface's IP address: chances are you cannot.

If you are under a Unix system, you can check what program listens on which port by using `netstat -ltpn`.

The basic system call for binding to a port is `listen(2)`.